# AWS MSK - Update storage volume size by modifying the CF

Tags: aws-msk

I have created an MSK cluster and all associated configuration using cloud formation template. Now I have to update the stack with more storage. Can I just modify the CF and specify the new storage requirement in the template and run the CF again?  Will it create a new MSK cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Updating a version in CF manifest will update a kafka version since May 2021.
Be sure, that you have enough disk space free for update though, otherwise you'll get the error: `Amazon CloudFormation wasn't able to complete the request because of an issue with the server.`

This operation will never create a new cluster since the cluster id will stay the same all the time